# Почему в верстке иногда используются альтернативный синтаксис управляющих структур php?

Tags: php, php7

Например,

```
if (..):
    ....
endif;
```

Ведь обычный синтаксис, со скобками, удобнее:

```
if (..) {
    ....
}
```

То же самое и для других структур (foreach-endforeach и т.д.).
Также, скобки у обычного синтаксиса подсвечивают почти все редакторы, а для альтернативного нет.
Чем обусловлено использование альтернативного синтаксиса в верстке?

Comment: Когда разработчик решает смешать код с версткой в одну кучу какашек, то `endif` разглядеть там проще чем `}`. вот и все.

Answer (score 0):

как для меня, альтернативный синтаксис удобнее когда нужно сочетать ветвления/циклы и разметку. с традиционным вариантов нужно выводить хтмл-разметку из php

Comment: нет, не нужно, работают они одинаково

Answer (score -1):

Для вёрстки блоков через PHP. Допустим, чтобы по условию if отображался либо блок "Зарегестрироваться" + "Войти", либо "Здравствуйте, имя" + "Выйти"